# Minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm

I have searched a lot for an answer to the following question:

Given is a connected undirect graph G = (V, E) with weight function w: E->R.

T1 is a minimum spanning tree of G with a weight of W1.

Add to the graph G a new edge with a weight of w(e) (the vertex connects two existing vertices in G).

T2 is a minimum spanning tree of the updated graph with a weight of W2.

Prove or disprove each statement:

1. If W1 = W2, the edge e is on a cycle with the weight of each edge on that cycle at most w(e).
2. W2 >= W1 - w(e)
3. If W2 < W1, the new edge e is on cycle with the weight of each edge on that cycle (except for e) larger than w(e).

Comment: Is the assumption correct that this is a pasted homework assignment? What have you tired so far?

Comment: Please rephrase the question in a more formal way; is `e` supposet to be an edge or a vertex?

Comment: e - suppose to be edge

Comment: I edited your question for clarity. You are confusing edges and vertices. A vertex is a node of your graph (usually depicted as a small circle with the node ID in or near that circle); an edge is a line connecting two vertices.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that you're just copying your coursework here.  It doesn't quite look like you've done anything to solve this, which is where my concern comes from.  Are you just lost or do you have some sort of attempt here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note the following:

Since `G` is a connected graph, adding an edge `e` between two existing vertices will create a cycle in `G`.

Statement 1: We have that W1 = W2. By contradiction. Assume that there is a cycle in G with both `e` and an edge `e'` with `w(e') > w(e)`. Since both edges `e` and `e'` are on the same cycle, we can remove one of them and still get a spanning tree. If we remove `e'`, we get that `W2 = W1 - w(e') + w(e)`. Since `w(e') > w(e)`, this implies `W2 < W1`, which contradicts the premis. It follows that the statement is true.

Statement 3 follows directly from the above.

Statement 2 is false, since we can give a counter example. Assume a graph `G = (V, E, w)`with `V = {A, B, C}` and edges `E = {e1 = (A, B), e2 = (A, C)}` with `w(e1) = 10`and `w(e2) = 11`. `G` is a minimum spanning tree with weight `W1 = 21`. Now add the edge `e = (B, C)` with weight `w(e) = 1`. The minimum spanning tree now consists of the edges `e1` and `e` and has a weight of `W2 = 11`. Plug those values into the equation `W2 >= W1 -w(e)`: `11 >= 21 - 1`, which is obviously not true, thus providing a counterexample to the claim.